# Existence of a matrix similar to upper triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

> Suppose that $X \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$, then there exists a nonsingular $S \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$ s.t $$S^{-1}XS= \begin{pmatrix} 
> P_{1} &  &   &   \\ 
>  &P_{2}  &\  & \bigstar  \\ 
>  &   & \ddots  &  \\ 
>   &  &   & P_{m}  \\
> \end{pmatrix}$$ is block upper triangular, where each $P_i \in M_1(\mathbb R)$ or of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ -a & b
> \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ for some $b>0$.

My intuition tells me that the Schurs Triangularization theorem will do the thing but I don't know how to use the said theorem or is there any method that will solve this. 
 
 Any hints and help would be much very appreciated.